# Connecting a Washing Machine with Aquastop

Tags: washing-machine

We've just moved into a new flat and bought a new washing machine. The provided cable isn't long enough to fit to the water outlet.

I bought an extension cable, along the lines of this:
https://www.bunnings.com.au/kinetic-1000mm-flexible-water-connector_p4750083

But I'm not certain if these needs to go before or after the Aquastop. The Aquastop is the electric variety but there is no additional cable to the maschine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to put the extension between the Aquastop and the machine, so that the Aquastop can stop the water supply even if there's a leak in the extension hose.